# Beagleboard Angstrom Linux, Image Capture Script streamer alternative

Tags: linux, webcam, beagleboard, image-capture, angstrom-linux

I want to take a snapshot from my logitech webcam with desired resolution and save the image by using linux bash script. I need to do it on my beagleboard with Angstrom image. In my beagleboard i can capture with using cheese. But i dont know how to capture in terminal with script.

In my host computer i am using streamer with

```
streamer -c /dev/video0 -b 16 -o outfile.jpeg
```

But i dont know how to take snapshots in Angstrom. Can you make suggestions?
How can i capture with command line?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I've used mjpg-streamer with some success. It sends a video stream through port 8080, although you can change that by editing the startup script.

I used instructions from [here](http://shrkey.com/installing-mjpg-streamer-on-beaglebone-black/), although I skipped the *make install* part and just run it off my home directory. Worked both with the default Angstrom image and with Debian running off the SD card (i.e., non-flashed).

You can view the stream by pointing your browser (either local or over-the-LAN) to http://beagle.address:8080/?action=*x*, where *x* is stream or snapshot. I trust those parameters are self-explanatory :).

You can use a text-based browser such as links to open the URL, and links will then prompt you for the filename of the image. That's for testing, then I suppose you can find a way to save the snapshot without human intervention if you intend to use it from a script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gstreamer to capture webcam input on Beaglebone using a logitech webcam. You'll need gstreamer with gstreamer-utils installed. I'm using Ubuntu and they can be found from the standard repos. Here's the CLI command:

```
gst-launch v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpg
```

Unfortunately, I'm experiencing some issues after some images as the pipeline freezes on v4l2src. Maybe you'll have better luck with your setup.